# Terraform Key Pair and ASG

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created an ASG which spins up one instance. I want to ssh into that instance but I don't have a Key Pair to connect to on this instance. Is it possible to do either attach a Key pair to this spun up instance or am I doing wrong with ssh'ing into it.

I'm doing:

```
ssh -i MY_KEY.PEM ec2-user@PUBLIC_DNS
```

(I'm new to Terraform and AWS in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add key pairs to AWS instances during runtime, as those are provisioned when the system starts up. So if you update the launch configuration / template and let it replace the ASG's instances, then you might be able to log in.

Whether you can then access the instance using given SSH command depends on, if you've set up the rest correctly. If you show us the complete terraform code, we might give more specific pointers, but in general, things to keep in mind are:

- instance must be in a public subnet, i.e., an Internet Gateway must be attached and the default route pointing to it
- a security group assigned to the instance must allow incoming TCP traffic on port 22 from *your* public IP